# Misterious `classMethod` test in Gradle Scala unit testing with JUnit 4

Tags: scala, unit-testing, junit, gradle, junit4

I'm having an issue with Gradle, JUnit and Scala test execution, in our [Scala language extension for Vert.x](https://github.com/vert-x/mod-lang-scala). Recently we upgraded from Vert.x 2.1.RC1 to 2.1.RC2, we started seeing that in some environments such as our Cloudbees instance, test execution looks up a phantom method called `classMethod` in a test class, which does not exist, and the test times out. As a result of that, the rest of tests fail.

In this [console](https://vertx.ci.cloudbees.com/job/vert.x-mod-lang-scala/892/console) instance, you can see:

```
org.vertx.scala.tests.core.http.HttpTest > classMethod FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError: Timed out waiting for test to complete
```

We have no idea what this `classMethod` is, where it's coming from...etc. Even more spooky is that I'm unable to replicate it neither in my OSX nor Linux (RHEL7) environments, both with JDK 1.7u45 and 1.7u51.

The only way we've found to be to fix it so far is to revert to Vert.x 2.1.RC1 (see [console of run](https://vertx.ci.cloudbees.com/job/vert.x-mod-lang-scala/853/console) with RC1), but we're really unable to see the link between this and this misterious `classMethod`.

We've tried upgrading to Gradle 1.11 in case it's an issue with Gradle itself but no luck. We're currently using JUnit 4.11.

The only thing that looks slightly suspicious is how even though the project uses Scala 2.10.4, the Gradle Scala plugin seems to [bring in Zinc which appears to need Scala 2.9.2](https://vertx.ci.cloudbees.com/job/vert.x-mod-lang-scala/893/console). When I wiped out my `.gradle/` folder locally, I didn't see any Scala 2.9.2 being downloaded. I wonder if this is messing up things?

Finally, for this last run when [HttpCompressionTest](https://github.com/vert-x/mod-lang-scala/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/vertx/scala/tests/core/http/HttpCompressionTest.scala) seem to have that `classMethod`, I've compared the `javap` output [locally](https://gist.github.com/galderz/76a025d754ab2e59c062) with [the one in Cloudbees](https://gist.github.com/galderz/76f885dbf7b0fd67422c), and they look identical.

I'm out of ideas, any suggestions?

UPDATE: As a last resort, I decided to upgrade to Vert.x 2.1.RC3-SNAPSHOT and it's all [back to normal](https://vertx.ci.cloudbees.com/job/vert.x-mod-lang-scala/896/console). I've absolutely no idea why, but I'll take it :)

Comment: Ive seen a similar classMethod failure.  what is it?

Comment: No idea, it would appear it was something wrong with that particular release jar. Any other snapshot after that has worked fine :|

Comment: We encountered the same error message. In our case, the reason was a bug of ours: a Vert.x verticle never replied, so the test blocked, forever, until the test runner killed it. In our case, the solution was to fix the bug. — When running on localhost, the bug wasn't triggered — only when running on our Jenkins machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior caused by (accidentally) having two different versions of the same lib on the classpath. Also, when a particular project is packaged as several different JARs, one of them was down-level from all the rest.